# Iterate over a nested object in Javascript and modify some of the items

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a nested object in Javascript, which I iterate on (with some help from lodash in this case). Simplified like here:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mREod64FMBxsQqN7m1NR?p=preview)

```
$scope.arr = [{
  id: 1,
  items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}, {
  id: 2,
  items: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}, {
  id: 3,
  items: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
}];

_.each($scope.arr, function(node) {
  node.id = "item_" + node.id; /* this works fine */
  _.each(node.items, function(item) {
    item = "item_" + item; /* this does not modify anything */
  });
});
```

Iterating over the first level works fine, probably as the 'node' variable is recognised to belong to the originating array - which is not the case on the second level, there's no binding, like PHP's &$var functionality.

How would you do this? One option is of course to even use the key and something like

```
node.items[itemKey] = '...';
```

Is that the only/smartest way?

Comment: Use `_.map`, as in `node.items = _.map(node.items, function(item) { return "item_" + item; })`.

Comment: Nope, that does not work, same result as with the _.each().

Comment: See http://jsbin.com/fazukehecu/edit?html,css,js,output.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the "node.items = " of course. Great - thanks!